# Installing mapnik-rasterizers fails

Tags: installation, mapnik

I want to install mapnik-rasterizers according to the README from here: https://github.com/stellaeof/mapnik-rasterizers

The problem now is that "make install" gives me this error message:

```
hiwi1102@hiwi1102:~/mapnik-rasterizers-master$ make install
make: mapnik-config: Kommando nicht gefunden
make: mapnik-config: Kommando nicht gefunden
make: mapnik-config: Kommando nicht gefunden
g++ -c  -fPIC -I/usr/include/agg2  -MMD -MP -MF .heatmap_datasource.cpp.d heatmap_datasource.cpp -o heatmap_datasource.os
In file included from rasterizer_datasource.hpp:11:0,
                 from heatmap_datasource.hpp:10,
                 from heatmap_datasource.cpp:7:
chained_datasource.hpp:12:30: schwerwiegender Fehler: mapnik/feature.hpp: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Kompilierung beendet.
make: *** [heatmap_datasource.os] Fehler 1
hiwi1102@hiwi1102:~/mapnik-rasterizers-master$
```

Could anybody help me out on this issue?

I've got python-mapnik2 running on my machine
apt-show-versions python-mapnik2 shows: python-mapnik2/precise uptodate 2.0.0+ds1-3build1
Ubuntu-Version: Ubuntu 12.04.1.

The error message with this fork (https://github.com/springmeyer/mapnik-rasterizers ) after "make install"

```
hiwi1102@hiwi1102:~/mapnik-rasterizers-master$ make install 
make: mapnik-config: Kommando nicht gefunden
make: mapnik-config: Kommando nicht gefunden
make: mapnik-config: Kommando nicht gefunden
g++ -c  -fPIC -I/Users/dane/projects/mapnik/deps/agg/include  -MMD -MP -MF .heatmap_datasource.cpp.d heatmap_datasource.cpp -o heatmap_datasource.os
In file included from rasterizer_datasource.hpp:11:0,
                 from heatmap_datasource.hpp:10,
                 from heatmap_datasource.cpp:7:
chained_datasource.hpp:12:30: schwerwiegender Fehler: mapnik/feature.hpp: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Kompilierung beendet.
make: *** [heatmap_datasource.os] Fehler 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The original author is not currently maintaining the rasterizers code. Please use my fork at https://github.com/springmeyer/mapnik-rasterizers. Depending on your mapnik version I will need to make a few tweaks to the code, so please post issues with your mapnik version and exact errors based on trying to compile from my fork.

Comment: I added the error message after trying to install your rasterizers fork to my first question.